# Show block menu links only on certain pages

Tags: navigation

I've built a menu with 20 links aprox. Then I put the block drupal creates for my menu on a region. Thing is I want some of the links to show for some pages, while others are hidden, like the option called "visibility options" on admin/structure/block/manage/block/nodenumber/

i.e.:
links 1,2 and 3 should be visible on page node/1
links 1,3 and 5 should be visible on page node/2
links 3,5 and 6 should be visible on page node/3

Any advice on how can I make it possible?

NOTE: Sorry for my english but it's not my native tongue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any additional information about the links inside your menu, it seems the easiest way to structure this is to create 3 separate menus, even if some of the links inside them are repeated.

What sort of links are those? Maybe you can use Views to create a Block that reacts to the page it's on to filter out the relevant links.